# Style adressing in the first person, "My Majesty", the King

Tags: writing-style, honorifics

Can style adressing be used in the first person, as in "I, My Majesty, King Charles, by the Grace of God..." instead of:

> I, Charles the Third, by the Grace of God of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of My other Realms and Territories, King, Defender of the Faith

([Source](https://www.royal.uk/his-majesty-kings-oath-relating-security-church-scotland))

P.S. I don't wanna debate wether it sounds arrogant or not, all I wanna know is if it's grammatically correct.

Comment: I don't think *grammar* is what makes this abominable etiquette.

Comment: That would sound more hilarious than arrogant. But it wouldn't be ungrammatical.

Comment: Being "grammatically correct" doesn't mean that it's semantically correct.

Comment: This makes an interesting philosophical situation, does semantic incongruity entail grammatical incorrectness. Can one refer to oneself as 'my majesty'? People refer to themselves in the third person and that is notoriously strange but it still follows phrase structure grammar. But "I, My Majesty..." is hard to process semantically... can one be one's own 'majesty'? Which is to say it may be grammatical or it may not...one would need to analyze the grammar of things like 'your highness' and such to see if this fits the pattern.

Comment: Perhaps look back a couple hundred years to find texts where a king refers to himself as "my majesty".

Comment: The practice of English monarchs, at least, seems to be to use the plural when using the first person.

Comment: Majestic people don't tell you they're majestic, and humble people don't tell you they're humble. Although we won't deny either.

Comment: The English is “want to”. Certainly his Majesty would prefer that.

Comment: Yo! Ya shouldna said *wanna* doncha know!

Comment: @Acccumulation - The 'royal we', often the subject of jokes, was in fact only ever used when the monarch was making a formal announcement as a representative of the whole nation.

Comment: If you're the king, you can talk any way you like. You set the fashion and others follow you.

Answer (score 4):

No, forms of address such as *Your Majesty, Your Royal Highness* or *My Lord* are never used in the first person - not because of grammar, just because it isn't traditional usage.

Comment: How about my awesomeness :)

Answer (score -1):

I searched [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my%20awesomeness%2Cmy%20majesty&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20awesomeness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20majesty%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmy%20awesomeness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20majesty%3B%2Cc0) with two terms "my awesomeness" and "my majesty", apparently my majesty was used, mostly in ancient texts and translations but also relatively recent texts.

[image]

Book search results [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my%20majesty%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=XyhmY9qoJNfb4-EPrKGogAo&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwia1LLs2Jb7AhXX7TgGHawQCqAQ8tMDegQIDRAE&biw=1680&bih=836&dpr=2) and [2](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/The_Portraiture_of_His_Majesty_King_Char/N1s2rAFOygYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22my%20majesty%22&pg=RA4-PA269&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Most of the uses of 'My Majesty' as a title seem, as you say, to come from ancient Middle Eastern texts, which are obviously translations. The Shakespeare one - 'laid by my majesty' is not a form of address, and the Francis Bacon is a false positive from a page printed in two columns being scanned right across.

Comment: But some of these hits are good.

Comment: Absent something to distinguish a capitalised Majesty - an honorific, from lowercase majesty - an attribute, the Ngram is pointless and misleading. Additionally, the Ngram does not disregard such phrases as "My Majesty speaks wisely."